# Echo Server/Client Java and android applications

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple echo server/client application. The server side is a Java application, the client site is an Android application.

The client is meant to display what the user sent via the server site by a Toast message. But the problem is the message is always delayed.

The first time after sending a message, the Toast message I got is "null", the second time it shows the message that I sent the first time...

Thanks for the help!

```
Client:

public class Client extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText editText;
Button button;

String string2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client);

    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.client, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.65",1234);
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                dos.writeUTF(editText.getText().toString());
                dos.flush();
                string2 = dis.readUTF().toString();
                    dos.close();
                dis.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    };
    thread.start();

    Toast.makeText(this,""+string2,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Message sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

```
 Server:

 public class Server {

static Socket socket =null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            System.out.println("Server is on ");
            try {
                ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(1234);                 
                while(true){
                     socket = serversocket.accept();

                    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    String string = dis.readUTF();
                    this.sendToClient(string);
                    System.out.println("Message:  "+ string);
                    dis.close();
                    socket.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public void sendToClient(String str) throws IOException {

            OutputStream s = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dos = new DataOutputStream(s); 
            dos.writeUTF(str);                         

        }

    };
    thread.start();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making an assumption that is not true.  Namely that your thread that does the work of retrieving the string from the server will finish before you show the Toast.

In onClick, you have started a background thread where the work is done to retrieve string2.

However, you immediately show a toast (on the main UI thread) and include the current value of string2.  Because the background thread hasn't finished yet, string2 will not yet have been updated.

You should instead use an AsyncTask.  Do the DataOutputStream stuff in doInBackground and update your UI (show the Toast) in onPostExecute.  This will guarantee the order you desire.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

There are tons of other posts about AsyncTask here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I also tried to make the onClick's thread sleep for 1 second, normally the string should be sent already.But I still got the same problem...